# Run different modules in a test_file.js in javascript in mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

There are two functions in a file .
I want to run this two functions in the `test_a` file.
After I ran ,it only ran second module for all `it()`.
I want each module do these `it()` in their own function and I don't want to separate these two functions into two files.
Do you have any ideas? thanks!!

```
//a.js
var add_data = function(data) {
    var data_displayed = 5;
    //var label_name = data[0];
    if (data.length - data_displayed <= 1) // data[0] == label
        var data_start = 1;
    else
        var data_start = data.length - data_displayed;
    return data_start;
};
module.exports = add_data;
var prepend_label = function(label, data, start_index, end_index) {
    data = data.splice(start_index, end_index);
    console.log('before = ' + data);
    if (data[0] != label);
    console.log(data[0]);
    data.unshift(label);
    console.log('after = ' + data);
    return data;
};
module.exports = prepend_label;
//test_a.js
var add_data = require('./a.js');
var prepend_label_to_spliced_data = require('./a.js');
var expect = require("chai").expect;
describe("define test suite", function() {
    it("test add_data() : data.length - data_displayed <= 1", function() {
        var data = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];
        expect(add_data(data)).to.be.equal(1);
    });
    it("test add_data() : data.length - data_displayed > 1", function() {
        var data = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
        expect(add_data(data)).to.be.equal(1);
    });
});
//var prepend_label_to_spliced_data = require('./home.js');
describe("define test suite2", function() {
    it("test prepend_label() : data[0]!=label", function() {
        var data = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'];
        var data2 = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
        data2.unshift('x');
        expect(prepend_label('x', data, 1, data.length - 1)).to.be.equal(data2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple. You are overwriting the first export with the second. You need to export them both like

```
module.export = {
    prepend_label, add_data // es2015 syntax
}
```

And then reference the functions in the test file:

```
const aModule = require('./a');
// do something...
aModule.add_label('foo');
// ...
```